# Nesting dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After making some calls to an API, filtering the data and cleaning the values that are not needed, I obtain a dataframe of this type:

| timestamp_utc | event | iso | ticker | impact | region | passed | full_date_utc | time | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1711584000 | Maundy Thursday | MX | MXN | Low | Mexico | True | 2024-03-28 00:00 | 00:00 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711584000 | Maundy Thursday | NO | NOK | Low | Norway | True | 2024-03-28 00:00 | 00:00 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711584000 | ANZ Business Confidence | NZ | NZD | Medium | New Zealand | True | 2024-03-28 00:00 | 00:00 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711584000 | ECB Knot Speech | EU | EUR | Low | Euro Area | True | 2024-03-28 00:00 | 00:00 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711584000 | BoE Mann Speech | GB | GBP | Low | United Kingdom | True | 2024-03-28 00:00 | 00:00 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711584060 | Car Production YoY | GB | GBP | Low | United Kingdom | True | 2024-03-28 00:01 | 00:01 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711585800 | Retail Sales MoM Prel | AU | AUD | Medium | Australia | False | 2024-03-28 00:30 | 00:30 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711585800 | Housing Credit MoM | AU | AUD | Medium | Australia | False | 2024-03-28 00:30 | 00:30 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711585800 | Private Sector Credit MoM | AU | AUD | Low | Australia | False | 2024-03-28 00:30 | 00:30 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711585800 | Private Sector Credit YoY | AU | AUD | Low | Australia | False | 2024-03-28 00:30 | 00:30 | 2024-03-28 |
| 1711587600 | Consumer Inflation Expectations | AU | AUD | Low | Australia | False | 2024-03-28 01:00 | 01:00 | 2024-03-28 |

This dataframe will then be further filtered by printing only some columns on the screen.
The final goal would be to generate an HTML table that avoids showing the same values redundantly, creating larger cells to show the value only once. This would be the effect I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

How can I filter the dataframe to get a similar result? How can I merge two cells of a dataframe if the value is identical? Are there specific functions in `pandas` to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Hey Itprorh66, im not a new here on SO. I understand that the code is missing, but the point is that I just can't understand the type of approach I need to use, I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, but to show me the right way.

Comment: You need to sort by ["time", "ticket", "impact"] and then take care of presentation on the client side. For example [`datatables`](https://datatables.net/) can be configured to present as you want.

Comment: Thanks SomeDude, I'll try to sort them as you suggested and take a look at that framework that you mentioned! ✌